# Derivation of Scattering Equation 9.88 in Thornton & Marion

Tags: classical-mechanics, scattering

I am confused as to how a particular equation in Thornton & Marion's 'Classical Dynamics of Particles and Systems' was derived.  It is equation 9.88, on page 354 of the fifth edition.

An incoming particle, $m_1$, is fired with kinetic energy $T_0$ at a stationary particle, $m_2$.  After the collision, the incident particle $m_1$ deflects at an angle $\psi$ with kinetic energy $T_1$, while the target particle $m_2$ deflects at an angle $\zeta$ with kinetic energy $T_2$.  All quantities are measured in the lab frame.

The equation in question is
$$
\frac{T_2}{T_0} = 1 - \frac{T_1}{T_0} = \frac{4m_1m_2}{(m_1+m_2)^2}\cos^2(\zeta).
$$
The only seemingly relevant equation given immediately before this equation is the following:
$$
\frac{T_1}{T_0} = \frac{m_1^2}{(m_1+m_2)^2} \left[ \cos{\psi} \pm \sqrt{ (\frac{m_2}{m_1})^2 - \sin^2{\psi}} \right]^2.
$$ 
I am sure that the second equation must somehow lead to the first, but I don't see how.  If I could find a relation between $\zeta$ and $\psi$, I am sure that would help.